# Adding "objects collisions" in the "collisions layer"

Tags: xna, collision-detection, layer, collision

Currently, my Character uses a collision layer with pixel-Perfect.
I added some objects like "doors" or "Platforms" in my game, but my character pass through them.

I think I could modify the collision layer each Update() with something like "merging".
Merging the collision layer with every objects I suppose, but I don't know how to do it...

[edited]
Q1 : how to merge some `Texture2D` in one ?

Thx for reading, hope you'll guide me.

Comment: There's still no answer, if i'm not clear enough, just tell me :x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using `RenderTargets`. Here's a [related question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18388/how-do-i-use-render-targets-in-xna) on how to use them.

Basically, you can draw all your collision sprites to the render target, making a single texture out of multiple ones. You can do this on each frame if your collision layer changes often.

Hope this helps!

Edit: Here's the [MSDN article on RenderTargets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.rendertarget%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx)

More edits: Alternatively, you could check your per-pixel collision on each of the objects instead of merging them all into one. However, you would have to show some code in order to get help for that.

Comment: "More edits: Alternatively, you could check your per-pixel collision on each of the objects instead of merging them all into one. However, you would have to show some code in order to get help for that."
I'm currently using this method. But i'll try using `RenderTarget`.
Thx for the tip !

Comment: After few minutes, i'v realized i have to use the "MergedTexture2D" at the beginning of the `Update()`.
But I can only use `RenderTarget` in the `Draw()` Method :x
So I can't use my Character's collision Detection on it. Is there a different way to allow merging `Texture2D` in an `Update()` ?

Comment: You could either pass a spritebatch to your `update` method (but I don't recommend it, I think it's confusing to have draw calls during an update) or you could save the rendertarget in a variable and analyse it during the _next_ `update` call. You'll be roughly 1/60 second late, but I think it'll be hardly noticable.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge Texture2D via the .SetData and .GetData -Methods

Be careful with the methods though, as they really eat framerate.

Comment: I'm going to edit my post because the real question is : how to merge some `Texture2D` in one.

Comment: This technique could be great but will be pretty tricky with my code because the differents `Texture2D` i'm using have not the same size. Thx anyway !

Comment: could you please show how your collision system is currently implemented?